# NP-complete problems

Tags: complexity-theory

I have come into NP-complete problems and I can't tell when the problem is NP-complete.
Is there a shortcut to know whether a given problem is NP-complete or not so that I don't waste time thinking about a fast algorithm?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only easy way to show that a problem is NP-Hard is to convert an already known NP-complete problem into this problem in polynomial time. Meaning the conversion should be calculated in polynomial time with respect to the size of the input. In this case, you know that the problem you have is NP-Hard, which means it is at least as hard as NP-Complete but may be more difficult.

At this point, you could stop trying to find a solution for it.

But if you also need to show that it is NP-complete, then you need to show that a solution could be check in polynomial time.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook%E2%80%93Levin_theorem for the hard way to do it.  Luckily that only had to be done once and then we can use the easy way forever after.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way.

If you can transform a known NP-complete problem in an instance of  your problem in polynomial time, than you know that your problem is also an NP-complete problem.

If you cannot find such a transformation, you simply don't know if it is NP-complete.

Comment: That transformation only shows that the problem is NP-Hard. You also need to show that a solution could be check in polynomial time if you really want to show that it is NP-complete.

Comment: @Nuri Tasdemir: If the transformation between the problems can be done in polynomial time, you can check it in polynomial time.

Comment: But the transformation was from a known NP-complete problem, let's say Y, to your own problem, say X. Therefore we know how to check an answer of a case in Y in polynomial time. However we do not have a way to check an answer of X in polynomial time. And we do not have a way to convert X into Y. It was the opposite.

Comment: We do not require transformation in both ways. Usually proving that an answer could be check in polynomial time is much easier than transformations.

Comment: Instead of finding back transformation you can of cause simply show that your problem is NP which might be easier.